# How do I make a if/then line in python

Tags: python, discord

My discord bot detects for a word and sends a role id to ping that role. I want to create a if then statement so if the message it detects doesn't include a certain word, it goes to the next line and looks for the next word in the script. I'm using replit as my host for the bot, so the line "from keep_alive import keep_alive" is the uptime bot, and the twenty at the end of the code is the hidden discord auth token. I am trying to add the if/then/advance line between the two trigger words

```
import discord
import os
client = discord.Client()

from keep_alive import keep_alive

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('Trigger Word'):
        await message.channel.send('<@&Role ID>')
    

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
      return    
   
    if message.content.startswith('Random Trigger Word'):
        await message.channel.send('<@&Role ID>')

keep_alive()
client.run(os.environ['20'])
```

Comment: @PatrickParker I'm not sure you read the question before patronizing the asker. They wrote a poor title, but the question text clearly describes what they're trying to do, and your comment doesn't speak to it.

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question. But since Adam found it "clear", I've removed my comment. (p.s. was not trying to "patronize" be careful reading motives onto others)

Answer (score 0):

You can't in this context, since both blocks are separate coroutines.

You could instead adjust your condition so only one could possibly be met.

```py
# on the first:
if message.content.startswith("Trigger Word") and \
        not message.content.startswith("Random Trigger Word"):
    # do the thing

...

# on the second
if message.content.startswith("Random Trigger Word") and \
        not message.content.startswith("Trigger Word"):
    # do the thing
```

---

Or if you have a mapping of triggers -> roles

```py
some_mapping = {"TriggerWord1": "role1",
    "TriggerWord2": "role2",
    "TriggerWord3": "role3"}

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    for trigger, role in some_mapping.items():
        if message.startswith(trigger):
            await message.channel.send(f'<@&{role}>')
```

Comment: If I do this, what I'm getting is that I will have to add multiple words and make it recursive. Is it possible to have a database of words and if it detects specific word, it returns the role associated with that word?

Comment: @DiscordWelcomeBot sure! I'd construct a dictionary of `{"trigger word": "role"}`, then iterate over that dict.items() and do `for trigger_word, associated_role in my_dict.items(): if message.content.startswith(trigger_word): await message.channel.send(f"<@{associated_role}")`

Comment: I tried that out, but I couldn't get the code to run. Is there a specific way to put it? I tried splitting it up like the rest of the code at ... .startswith(random_trigger_word) *enter* await message.channel.send(role_id) and it still didn't work.